# how to load more data in the tableview when the tableview reaches its last row in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

im trying to do load more data of an api when the tableview reaches its last row using its page number in the api like instagram feed....I need help to resolve this...could somebody help me with the code...

1. I need to know that whether I have to keep one method for loading data from json and also have the same method for load more data?
   2.if I run my code im getting the 1st page data correctly and the second page has only one record but whenever the tableview is scrolling from the last row of the tableview it is displaying multiple time.

could somebody please help me to do this...

Here im fetching my json data in

> -(void)fetch data

```
 NSString *urlstring = @"https://bsedemo.com/instasocial/api/post/feeds?user_id=402&&access_token=$2y$10$TWX2Ym1gM4NBjGCNzTydzuQTZWPcK2tMVw1eWdWvYDFmO4CsKc1kC&&page_no=1&&feed_type=3&&feed_id=&&member_id=402";
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSData *url_data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *loaded_jsondata_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:url_data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    data_values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(dict in [loaded_jsondata_dict objectForKey:@"result"])
    {
        [data_values addObject:dict];
    }
    [tableview reloadData];
```

here is my table view cell

> cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
TableViewCellVC *cell = [[TableViewCellVC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
cell=[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
media= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCellVC" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
cell.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 23.5;
cell.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl1.jpg"];
cell.usernameLabel.text= [[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"user_name"];
cell.lastseenLabel.text =[[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"created_at"];
cell.commentcount.text =[[[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"post_comment_count"]stringValue];
cell.likecount.text =[[[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"post_like_count"]stringValue];
cell.discriptionLabel.text =[[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"post_text"];

media =[[data_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"media"];
media_dict = media[0];
NSString *media_urlstring =[media_dict valueForKey:@"media_name"];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *media_url =[NSURL URLWithString:media_urlstring];
    NSData *url_data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:media_url];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    cell.postImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:url_data];
});
});
media_height = [[media_dict valueForKey:@"media_height"]floatValue];
media_width =[[media_dict valueForKey:@"media_width"]floatValue];
CGFloat screensize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
cell_height =(((screensize/media_height)*media_width)-340);
return cell;
```

here is my load more data method and scrollviewdidscroll method

> -(void)loadmoredata

```
 NSString *urlstring = @"https://bsedemo.com/instasocial/api/post/feeds?user_id=402&&access_token=$2y$10$TWX2Ym1gM4NBjGCNzTydzuQTZWPcK2tMVw1eWdWvYDFmO4CsKc1kC&&page_no=2&&feed_type=3&&feed_id=&&member_id=402";
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSData *url_data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *loaded_jsondata_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:url_data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
data_values_2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *page2_dict in [loaded_jsondata_dict objectForKey:@"result"])
{
    [data_values_2 addObject:page2_dict];
}
if(data_values.count-1)
{
    [data_values addObjectsFromArray:data_values_2];
}
[activity_indicator stopAnimating];
[tableview reloadData];
```

scrollviewdidscrollmethod

> scrollviewdidscrollmethod

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

int scrollViewContentHeight = tableview.contentSize.height;
int scrollOffset = scrollViewContentHeight -tableview.bounds.size.height;
if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollOffset && tableview.isDragging)
  {
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,tableview.contentSize.height,tableview.bounds.size.width,60);
     activity_indicator.frame = frame;
     [activity_indicator startAnimating];
     [self loadMoreData];
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue?  Is this question another one about the asynchronous thing again?

Comment: the issue is the data in the second page is repeatedly loading in the tableview when ever the user is scrolling the tableview...

Comment: Why are you telling the scroll guy to load more data when in fact it's the table guy that is running the show?

Comment: Use the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method instead.

Comment: @ElTomato -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row ==data_values.count-1)
    {
        [activity_indicator startAnimating];
        [self loadMoreData];
    }
}

Comment: if I do this in my willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method my tableview is flickering and it is hard to scroll and the same issue of data displaying multiple time...can u help me what should I do with my code

Comment: I don't know what you have with loadMoreData.  Suppose that you load 50 records at a time, which gives you the current page whenever you load data.

Comment: @ElTomato please lookup the above posted code there I posted the loadmoredata method code

Comment: could you explain me with some example or do changes in my code please

Comment: If I were you I would pull a ton of the JSON at once (JSON is lightweight) enough for scrolling and then you load the heavy stuff like images only when the cells appear. When you get to the bottom of the table (measure table y offset), call the API again, from the last downloaded ID onwards.